# how to set up mysql with meteor

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, meteor

I have seen a few things about how to use mysql with meteor but never a compete guide on how to set it up. That is what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is a package called `numtel:mysql` give it a try `meteor add numtel:mysqlwith`

Check [package here](https://atmospherejs.com/numtel/mysql)

also there is  full example to setup the leandboard (Meteor main example) with sql reactive data.

Check the  [Leaderboard example with SQL](https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql-leaderboard)